# Get Property of Observable

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

Back in E3 the following was the correct way to create an `IObservableValue`:

```java
modelObservable = PojoObservables.observeDetailValue((IObservableValue) this.model, this.property, null);
// or
modelObservable = PojoObservables.observeValue(this.model, this.property);
```

Then you could get the property from this `modelObservable` via:

```java
String property = ((IBeanObservable) modelObservable).getPropertyDescriptor().getName();
```

Now with E4, the correct way to create an `IObservableValue` is:

```java
modelObservable = PojoProperties.value(this.property).observeDetail((IObservableValue) this.model);
// or
modelObservable = PojoProperties.value(this.property).observe(this.model);
```

However, the method `getPropertyDescriptor()` now returns null. How can I get the property of this `modelObservable` in a general way?

Answer (score 0):

The best I can do is this method:

```java
public static final String findProperty(final IObservable target) {
    String property = null;

    if (target instanceof IBeanObservable) {
        final PropertyDescriptor desc = ((IBeanObservable) target).getPropertyDescriptor();
        property = desc == null ? null : desc.getName();
    }
    if (property == null && target instanceof DecoratingObservableValue) {
        property = getPropertyOfDecorator((DecoratingObservableValue<?>) target);
    }
    return property;
}

private static String getPropertyOfDecorator(DecoratingObservableValue<?> target) {
    try {
        final Field decoratedField = DecoratingObservableValue.class.getDeclaredField("decorated");
        decoratedField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object decorated = decoratedField.get(target);
        if (decorated != null) {
            return findProperty((IObservable) decorated);
        }
        return null;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```